# StringFormat file size in datagrid column

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting, wpfdatagrid

I want to display in a datagrid column size of a directory but I don't know how to format the string with "StringFormat" in XAML to display KB , MB or GB and keep the ability to sort by size .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an additional property in ItemsSource of the data grid. Populate that new property with the size of directory keeping unit a constant. So let say you have a directory with 100 KB and another with 1 MB. So convert 1 MB into equivalent KB and populate in the newly added property. Do not show this property on Datagrid just use it in sort member path. and keep the string property in View which would show 100 KB or 1 MB values. To better understand what I am trying to say, please refer [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660847/sort-wpf-datagrid-with-integer-appended-with-string)

Let me know if things are not clear to you !!

Comment: Let's say I have a  property double "Size" and a String property "SizeWithUnit" , I display on the datagrid "SizeWithUnit" but I use Size as sort member path ?

Comment: Exactly. That's what you need to do.

Comment: My property is in a list so I have to do like this ?

`SortMemberPath="{Binding Path=Size}`

Comment: No, do it like SortMemberPath="Size" and make sure that Size property is part of attached ItemsSouce of List.